# Siebel - ACTIVE_FLG

Tags: siebel

Sibel eMedia (V 8.1):

There is this field Active in Quote BC and Order BC.

The field is associated to the column ACTIVE_FLG in both the Business Components. 
But I find that in many instances the ACTIVE_FLG values are not in sync for a quote and its corresponding order.

The column has values 'Y' for a quote and 'N' for it's corresponding order.
Is this a Vanilla field? I couldn't determine its working.

I tried searching for scripts invoking the submit button to see if that had any effect on the field.But i could find any scripts for that too.

Comment: May be you get some clues from [this bookshelf article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/OrdMgt/OrdMgtEmployee_UI6.html#wp1045454).

Comment: Seconding Yaroslav. Siebel allows multiple versions of Quote/Order. There should be a field for version number, at a time, only only version should be Active. The reason you are seeing values different at Quote and Order is because the Active field might not be mapped in the Application Datamapper which copies Quote to Order. This is triggered via vanilla signals, I think.